mcfunction command that doesn't work on a chest_minecart but work perfectly on player
I'm new to mcfunction and in the making of datapacks in Minecraft 1.20 and I've got an issue with the GUI I made.
I'm trying to make a menu, where if the predicate I made is true then an item in the chest_minecraft get the glint effect so it look like it is selected.
I have this so far:
execute as @s if predicate custom_gui:has_dye run item replace entity @s container.14 with fishing_rod{display:{Name:'{"text":"fisherman","color":"yellow","bold":true}',Lore:['{"text":"", "color":"blue"}']},objd:{gui:1b},Enchantments:[{}]}
execute as @s unless predicate custom_gui:has_dye run item replace entity @s container.14 with fishing_rod{display:{Name:'{"text":"fisherman","color":"yellow","bold":true}',Lore:['{"text":"", "color":"blue"}']},objd:{gui:1b}}

and so far this work well when i manualy use '/function' on myself and using my player inventory as container but doesn't on the minecart. I maybe guess my function is badly called or somthing like that but i do not know a proper way to test that, if I can get so tips here as well it would help me a lot.
